# What is the value of $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\dfrac{f(x)-2}{x}-\dfrac{\sin x}{x^2}\right]=1$.

Then what is the value of $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$?

(Don't use $N$-$\epsilon$ language to compute this limit.)

Thanks for your help.

---

Somebody prefer to close my post. Here I give some explain. This question is asked by one of my friends and he don't be familar with  $N$-$\epsilon$ language. I don't know how to help to work it out by using simple idea?

Especially, how could I explain to him from that step
$$
1=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{1}{x}\left(f(x)-2-\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\right].
$$
to this step $$
0=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(f(x)-2-\frac{\sin x}{x}\right).$$

Comment: The question supposes that that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exists so the $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-2-\sin x/x)$ exists and equals to $L$ (could be $\pm\infty$). But if $L$ is anything but $0$, you won't have $\lim_{x\to 0}[(1/x)(f(x)-s-\sin x/x)]=1$ so $L$ is $0$. Please also see my post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\dfrac{f(x)-2}{x}-\dfrac{\sin x}{x^2}\right]=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\dfrac{f(x)-3}{x}+\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^2}\right]=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-3}{x}$$
so $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-3)=\lim_{x\to 0}[x\cdot\dfrac{f(x)-3}{x}]=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=3$.

Comment: How clould I to explain to him from $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-3}{x}$ to $\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)}=3$?

Comment: @Paul: Note that $f(x)-3=\frac{f(x)-3}{x}\cdot x$

Comment: I think the second equality in the first line must somehow be justified: the remaining limit $\;\lim\frac{f(x)-3}x\;$ exists because it is the difference of two (existing, of course) limits. Otherwise one can *not* deduce that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
1=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{f(x)-2}{x}-\frac{\sin x}{x^2}\right]=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{1}{x}\left(f(x)-2-\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\right].
$$
It follows that
$$
0=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(f(x)-2-\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\implies \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=2+1=3.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}}x=0$. So we obtain $\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}}f(x)-2-\frac{sinx}{x}=0$ by multiplying both sides of the equation by $\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}}x$ and applying   product rule (for limits) on the left. So $\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}}f(x)=3$